# Using nuxt-link in external component library

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

we are developing an NPM package with vue based components to use in different Nuxt based apps.
I'm not understanding which is the best strategy to use the "nuxt-link" component.

For example if I have a component like a product card :

```
<template>
  <a class="grid-layout-item " :href="href">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div
        class="absolute left-0 top-0 z-20 h-full w-full bg-gradient-overImage p-2 text-light md:p-4 lg:p-5"
      >
        <p class="pb-2 text-h9 uppercase text-light lg:pb-4">{{ heading }}</p>
        <h1 class="font-semibold text-h6">{{ title }}</h1>
        <h2 class="set-hover-underline font-light text-h6 group-hover:decoration-white">
          {{ subtitle }}
        </h2>
      </div>
      <img
        :class="[
          'hover-image-zoom absolute left-0 top-0 z-10 h-full w-full object-cover',
          greyImages && 'grayscale',
        ]"
        loading="lazy"
        :src="image"
        :alt="imageAlt ? imageAlt : 'image alt text'"
      />
    </div>
  </a>
</template>
```

how can i replace the a tag with nuxt-link tag?

the package needs to be published on NPM and then imported from the front-end code ( which is the classic NUXT3 + Sanity app )

thanks !

I've searched on documentation and forums but no luck. If I try to use the Nuxt-link element in the package it won't compile.

using  seems to be a possible way but I cannot use them as a "wrapping" item in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
<template>
   <NuxtLink class="grid-layout-item " :to="href">...</NuxtLink>
<template>

<script>
import { NuxtLink } from '#components'
</script>
```

That worked for me!